# Coinciding open sets

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

I'm given two distances that are defined on some metric space and I need to show that open sets and Cauchy sequences coincide for the two distances. What does this mean? I'm avoiding giving details on purpose, but a nice definition would help :)

I found that for two distances to be equivalent we need $\exists$ $0<c_1<c_2<\infty$ s.t. $c_1< d_1/d_2< c_2$, but in my particular case I can't find a particular lower bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote in your last paragraph is *strong* equivalence of metrics.
What you have to actually show is *weak* equivalence, that is that the two metrics define the same topology.

Without knowing more about your metrics, you need to show: If $U$ is open in the sense of $d_1$, then it is open in the sense of $d_2$. It suffices to show that for every open ball in the sense of $d_1$ and every point $x$ in that ball, there is a $d_2$-ball around $x$ contained in the given $d_1$-ball (and vice versa).
The statement about Cauchy sequences will then follow immediately.

Comment: So open sets are equivalent in both metrics?

Comment: @Atreyu: Yes, according to your vague question, that is exactly the first part what you said that you had to show.

Comment: Is this equivalent to showing if $d_1 (x,y)< \epsilon$ then this implies $\exists$ $\delta$ s.t. $d_2 (x,y)< \delta$ and vice-versa, or is this just a statement about open sets mapping to open sets? I mean it seems to me the way you stated it that in the condition I just mentioned $\epsilon = \delta$ (for both inclusions), or else they do not coincide.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably referring to equivalent metrics. Two metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ on a set $X$ are equivalent if and only if there exist positive constants $A$ and $B$ such that for all $x,y \in X$:
$$ A d_2(x,y)  \leq d_1(x,y) \leq B d_2(x,y).   $$

Then its easy to see that $O$ is open in $(X,d_1)$ iff it is open in $(X,d_2)$ and $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $(X,d_1)$ iff it is Cauchy in $(X,d_2)$.